# Section of sine / clipped sine

Tags: tikz-pic

I want to draw a limited sine curve.

My problem is, that I know how to draw 1/4 `sin` but not how to get only a section of it.

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin {nofloat}{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[ cross/.style={draw, cross out,
              minimum size=2*(#1-1pt), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, x=1cm, y=1cm]

               \colorlet{grey}{black!50}

               \draw[-,thick,dashed] (-4,2) node[left] {$UpperLimit$} -- (2,2);
               \draw[->,thick] (-4,1)   -- (2,1)node[right] {$t$};
               \draw[-,thick,dashed] (-4,0) node[left] {$LowerLimit$} -- (2,0);
               \draw[->,thick] (-3,-0.5)  -- (-3,2.5)node[above] {$\textcolor{grey}{u} |\textcolor{red}{ \ind{u}{Clipped}}$};

               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-3,1) sin (-2,2.5);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-2,2.5) cos (-1,1);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-1,1) sin (0,-0.5);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (0,-0.5) cos (1,1);

                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-3,1) sin (-2,2.5);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-2.53545,2)   -- (-1.46455,2);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-2,2.5) cos (-1,1);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-1,1) sin (0,-0.5);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-0.53545,0)   -- (0.53545,0);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (0,-0.5) cos (1,1);

          %     \draw [red,thick,domain=0:-2.53545] plot ( {1.5*sin(\x*2*pi/4)+1}); 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Effect of the Accuracy Shutdown}
        \label{fig:accshut}
    \end{nofloat}
\end{minipage}
```

I would like something like at the minimum but what I only can produce is something like the maximum.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please include complete minimum working examples, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` with all significant packages and own commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a clipping area before drawing the red line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
 %   \begin{nofloat}{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[ cross/.style={draw, cross out,
              minimum size=2*(#1-1pt), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, x=1cm, y=1cm]

               \colorlet{grey}{black!50}

               \draw[-,thick,dashed] (-4,2) node[left] {$UpperLimit$} -- (2,2);
               \draw[->,thick] (-4,1)   -- (2,1)node[right] {$t$};
               \draw[-,thick,dashed] (-4,0) node[left] {$LowerLimit$} -- (2,0);
               \draw[->,thick] (-3,-0.5)  -- (-3,2.5)node[above] {$\textcolor{grey}{u} |\textcolor{red}{d}$};

               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-3,1) sin (-2,2.5);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-2,2.5) cos (-1,1);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (-1,1) sin (0,-0.5);
               \draw[thick, dashed, grey] (0,-0.5) cos (1,1);

                    {
                    \clip (-3,0) rectangle (1,2);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-3,1) sin (-2,2.5);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-2.53545,2) -- (-1.46455,2);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-2,2.5) cos (-1,1);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-1,1) sin (0,-0.5);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-1,1) sin (0,-0.5);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (-0.53545,0)   -- (0.53545,0);
                \draw[ultra thick, red] (0,-0.5) cos (1,1);}

          %     \draw [red,thick,domain=0:-2.53545] plot ( {1.5*sin(\x*2*pi/4)+1}); 
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
%        \caption{Effect of the Accuracy Shutdown}
%        \label{fig:accshut}
%    \end{nofloat}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

an alternative, with use of `plot` functions and `intersections`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
LR/.style = {draw=red,  ultra thick,   line cap=round},
LG/.style = {draw=gray, thick, dashed, line cap=round},
        > = Straight Barb
                    ]
% limit
\def\LLV{1}   % <--- for setings of  limiter level value                 
% axis
\draw[->,thick] (-1,0.0) -- ++ (5,0.0) node[right] {$t$};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-2.2) -- ++ (0,4.4) node[above] {\textcolor{gray}{$u|$}%
                                                  \textcolor{red}{ $d$}};
% limits
\coordinate (UL) at (-0.5, \LLV); 
\coordinate (LL) at (-0.5,-\LLV); 
\draw[LG, name path=A]
    (UL) node[left] {\textit{UpperLimit}} -- ++ (4,0);
\draw[LG, name path=B]
    (LL) node[left] {\textit{LowerLimit}} -- ++ (4,0)
         coordinate (LD);
% sinusoide
\draw[thick, dashed, gray, name path=S]
    plot[domain=0:6.28, samples=60] (\x/2,{2*sin(\x r)});
\draw[LR,
      name intersections={of=A and S, by={u1,u2}}]
        (u1) -- (u2);
\draw[LR,
      name intersections={of=B and S, by={l1,l2}}]
        (l1) -- (l2);
% cliped sinusoide
\clip (UL) rectangle (LD);
\draw [LR]
    plot[domain=0:6.28, samples=60] (\x/2,{2*sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with setting `\LLV` you can easy change limiter clamping levels. with this is given additional flexibility of proposed solution.

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to limit it vertical ? like a Deadzone?
Something like: https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/34499039/clippedAndDeadzoneSine.png

Comment: yes, it is possible. but for this is a new question.  i suggest you to ask it, that it will be visible to wider audience.

Comment: I used the clipped solution below with two clippings (  `\clip (-2.8,1) rectangle (-1.2,2.025);` and  `\clip (-0.9,-0.32) rectangle (0.9,1);` 
 ) each placed between a `\begin{scope} \end{scope}`

Comment: i@chrisdi91, if this gives you desired result, than it is ok. if this belong to some new question, please write this as answer with your solution of the your new problem. here as comment is not well visible to audience an consequently to other members with similar problem